# Matching Users in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I suppose this is more of a ruby question than a rails question, but I'm confused as to how to match users based on their attributes in ActiveRecord. This may even be more of an algorithms thing, but I'm not positive.

Essentially I want to check if a user is following their friend, and if their friend is following them back, then they're both set as "true" for a "matched" boolean.

So you can see how my db is structured, currently I have a migration that looks like this:

```
class CreateRelationships < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :relationships do |t|
      t.integer :follower_id
      t.integer :followed_id

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :relationships, :follower_id
    add_index :relationships, :followed_id
    add_index :relationships, [:follower_id, :followed_id], unique: true
  end
end
```

I would like to check somehow by saying "if follower_id and followed_id = the inverse of each other, then set 'matched' to true", but I'm not sure if there's a better or "standard" way of doing this. Any advice would be greatly appreciated! Obviously I'm still pretty new to ruby, so this is a hurdle I'd like to understand.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this and test both directions

```
User.find(id).relationships.include?(User.find(followed_id))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 solutions depending on the context:

**You have only the ids of the 2 users:** check in DB there is 2 relationships with these users (one for each direction)

```
alice_id = ...
bob_id = ...
matched = Relationship.where(follower_id: [alice_id, bob_id], followed_id: [alice_id, bob_id]).count == 2
```

**You have the 2 users with the list of their followers**: I suppose you have a relation like `has_many :followers` in the `User` class, and the relation is loaded. So you don't need to do an extra query to the DB

```
alice_user = ...  # for example User.includes(:followers).find(alice_id)
bob_user = ...
matched = alice_user.followers.include?(bob_user) && bob_user.followers.include?(alice_user)
```